# Invoke Same Method for Multiple Services in Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor

My application consists of multiple services.We had a requirement now that for every request coming in to our application we need to validate the token.

Current architecture of my application is such that every microservice has its own ServiceInterceptor class and in that class I am writing the logic in prehandle method to validate token recieved in request.

Service Interceptor Class.

```
 @Component
 public class ServiceInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
 private static final ApplicationLogger logger = ApplicationLogger.getInstance();

 @Autowired
 TokenInfoServiceImpl tokenInfoServiceImpl;

@Override
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {      
    String requestPath = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String authToken = request.getHeader("authToken");
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String userId = request.getHeader("userId");
    
    if (deviceId.equals("web")) {
        if (bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            bearerToken = bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        } else {
           response.sendError(400, "Expected bearer prefix to Authorization header value.");
        }
        boolean isTokenValid = tokenInfoServiceImpl.validateToken(bearerToken);
        return isTokenValid;
        
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Post Handle method is Calling");
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        Exception exception) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Request and Response is completed");
}
}
```

My concern is since we have different services,every service has its interceptor class , so in every service will I have to create method validateToken(to validate the token when a request comes to that service) which is obviously not at all an ideal approach.
Is there a way that I could write validateToken method in one place and that could be accessed by all the services(like UserService,PaymentService,etc..) or rather one Interceptor could be used to intercept request for all the individual microservices instead of having separate interceptor for each service .

I know this can be done using API Gateway but right now our team want a quick solution to this .API Gateway will implement later.

Comment: I believe that all your services should have an interceptor which will call AuthService to validateToken (AuthService shouldn't be visible outside of inner network)

Comment: ok so in that case you suggesting that in every microservice I will have to write validateToken method??

Comment: well you can just write it in some utils library which will be included in every microservice and just invoke it from your interceptor. There are probably other solutions to your problem. It's just first one which I know about

Comment: Other one would be to just create some gateway before accessing any Service so it would be like having a redirect to authservice (it checks validity of token) then redirects or calls your service and return result to user. Here you assume that your auth service is always first in line for each call.

Comment: yes so anyways we will have to create one Util Class in every microservice and write that validate token method.I wanted to avoid that writing the same code in every microservice

Comment: nope you wouldn't

Comment: You can create project called for example validate, it will have one class ValidateToken with method which calls your AuthService then from each microservice you just do ValidateToken.isValid(token); (from interceptor) and that would be it. The only thing duplicated here would be interceptor itself and isValid call inside interceptor. You load library in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question & comments you can try below :

1. Create Configuration bean which implements [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html?msclkid=3d563dcac6dc11ecbd24ceb5c423ea30)
2. Use your `ServiceInterceptor` inside `addInteceptor` & mention endpoints or root context if all endpoints needed this config :

   ```
   @Configuration
    public class ConfigClass implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new ServiceInterceptor ()).addPathPatterns("/contextroot/**"); 
        }
    }
   ```

Also you may directly use your `ServiceInterceptor` without annotating it with `Component`.

Comment: I already have this class in every microservice

Comment: Depends on how you have implemented your microservices. If you have utility package which all microservices can able to access then you can put this config in utility package.

Comment: So you suggesting to get rid of service interceptor class from each microservice and put one interceptor class along with this config class in a separate util service.then how would other microservice use this class??I mean how would then I implement the logic in other microservices to intercept the requests.

Comment: One quick way comes in my mind is to use `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"util package"})` in every microserivice.